# Bitcoin trade to money you receive at Neteller to your Neteller creditcard?

Tags: bitcoin-credit-card

So can I trade Bitcoin at a site like localbitcoins.com to receive money in my Neteller account and add the money I received at this Neteller account to my Neteller creditcard?

Comment: Your title is tough to read. Maybe you mean "How to turn bitcoin into funds for Neteller credit card?".

Answer (score 1):

LocalBitcoins.com itself actually supports Neteller: https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/neteller/